# Problema con variables en python

Tags: python, tkinter

muy buenas estoy realizando un codigo el cual me ha de modificar las medidas de  un rectangulo en una imagen, el codigo lo he realizado con el metodo input y me funciona perfectamente el problema biene porque he querido hacer que la entrada sea bonita y he decidido hacer una caja de texto, pero no me funciona, soy nuevo en esto del python y la verdad es que me estoy enganchando pero ahora mismo ando anclado en este problema, he mirado y remirado codigos y los he probado pero ninguno me ha funcionado, les dejo el fragmento de codigo donde x1,y1,x2,y2 son las variables a sobreescribir por X1,Y1,X2,Y2. les estaré eternamente agradecido ya que no puedo avanzar y mi pequeño proyecto por culpa de esto. gracias

```
k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

if  k == ord('p'):
def aceptar():
    int(X1.get()) 
    int(Y1.get())  
    int(X2.get())
    int(Y2.get())
    X1 = x1
    Y1 = y1
    X2 = x2
    Y2 = y2
            
    root = Tk()
    X1 = StringVar()
    Y1 = StringVar()
    X2 = StringVar()
    Y2 = StringVar()

    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
    root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(2, weight=2)
    root.columnconfigure(3, weight=2)
    root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

    Label(root, text="x1:").grid(row=0, column=0)
    Label(root, text="y1:").grid(row=1, column=0)
    Label(root, text="x2:").grid(row=2, column=0)
    Label(root, text="y2:").grid(row=3, column=0)

    Entry(root,textvariable=X1).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E+W)
    Entry(root,textvariable=Y1).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E+W)
    Entry(root,textvariable=X2).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E+W)
    Entry(root,textvariable=Y2).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E+W)

    Button(root, text="Aceptar",command=aceptar).grid(pady=10,
                                                      padx=10,
                                                      row=4,
                                                      column=0,
                                                      columnspan=2,
                                                      sticky=S+N+E+W)
    root.mainloop()
```

PD: Si es necesario poner todo el codigo por favor digamelo y lo cuelgo entero

Comment: Hola @Pous podrias agregar mas información de lo que quieres lograr, gracias

Comment: Perdón si no se entiende la explicacion, en principio lo que hace el programa es abrir una ventana de video con un rectangulo donde dentro detectara un color, el problema es que necesito que con dicha ventana abierta se pueda modificar la posicion del rectangulo (x1,y1,x2,y2) donde el usuario pueda introducir las posiciones pero viendo donde queda al presionar "aceptar". Si necesitais mas información no dudeis en pedirla, que estoy verdaderamente frustrado.